# Windows10 HostFile Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: windows, dns, hosts

I wanted to change my hostfile to access Keycloack locally. I tried to change my hostFile (with admin rights) but i can only change it in Safe Mode

I added the following line:

127.0.0.1   keycloak

If I try to ping keycloak, he tries to ping 27.0.0.1.

Any ideas why this behaviour occurs ?

Comment: Perhaps the digit "1" is really the letter "l" or "I". Use a font in your editor that clearly distinguishes these, e.g. Inconsolata or Atkinson Hyperlegible.

Comment: As above, or remove it and type it in again ensuring you're using number keys.

Comment: i made sure that the input is 

127.0.0.1 test
127.0.0.1 keycloak

The ping on tst works correctly, but the with keycloak the same behaviour occurs

Comment: I found the problem, in the file host.ics the setting was incorrect